# Отслежка открытия письма при рассылке

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail

Вставляю в письмо однопиксельную картинку с ссылкой для отслежки открытия письма при email-рассылке. Но мейл меняет ссылку, и из-за этого запрос на мой сервер не поступает. Как быть? Специальные сервисы можно не предлагать, нужно всё реализовать самому.

Comment: `Как быть?` перестать следить за пользователем

Comment: @bigstar, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вы никак не сможете такое сделать, если пользователь пользуется email-сервером, который меняет ссылки. Сервер делает это как раз против отслеживания и кражи данных. Других способов тоже не существует. Разве только вы как-то переманите жертву пользоваться другим email-сервером, который не меняет ссылки.

Но одно возможное решение может быть: напишите в письме что-то, на что жертва сразу откликнется. К примеру: «Посылаю тебе 10000 рублей». И при этом их не пошлите.